# Make the checkbox checked on selection of Select all in wpf

Tags: wpf, checkbox, listbox

How do i make all the checkbox clicked when i click Select All and it should deselect when i uncheck Select all . Please let me know .

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Inputbinding}" >
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectAll" Content="Select All" />
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkjon" Content="Jon" />
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkbob" Content="Bob" />
 <CheckBox x:Name="chkmary" Content="Mary" />                
</ListBox>
 <Button  x:Name="btnUserName"  Height="25"  Margin="0,10,10,0"
      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsButtonEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}" Click="BtnInput_Click"  >
    <TextBlock >Submit</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
   <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectAll" Content="Select All" />
   <CheckBox x:Name="chkjon" Content="Jon" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=chkSelectAll,Mode=OneWay}" />
   <CheckBox x:Name="chkbob" Content="Bob"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=chkSelectAll,Mode=OneWay}" />
   <CheckBox x:Name="chkmary" Content="Mary"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=chkSelectAll,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

[image]